# Peoples reputation vanishing

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, badges

So this one person has a ton of badges but one reputation! I don't think this is possible unless there's

A. A bug

B.(unlikely) his questions got flagged as SPAM.

I've seen this happen to a lot of people and it's really annoying because I can't see people's reputation. Please fix.
I have a picture of it here...
[image]

My real question is: why does this happen? Thanks.
This has happened to about ten profiles I clicked on.

Comment: "it's really bad", no the people have been bad.

Comment: Why the down-votes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a bug. Retrosaur normally has tens of thousands of reputation points and earned those badges through normal use of the site. Right now this user is on a temporary suspension, so the rep was temporarily set to 1 by the system. You can see the suspension info by clicking on the user's profile page.

> This account is temporarily suspended to cool down. The suspension period ends on Jul 9 at 23:22.

Once the suspension ends, the user's reputation points will go back to normal.

The specific reasons why a user was suspended are private between the moderators and the suspended user, but in general it is because the user has a pattern of not putting in the effort to learn and improve over time or a pattern of disruptive behavior.

[More information about temporary suspension can be found on this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/)

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm on mobile so I can't see that

Comment: @Alex no worries, i'm glad its not a bug :D

Comment: is there a way to see why someone is on suspension or is that a mod only feature?

Comment: @Alex the reasons for a suspension are private between the mods and the user